# Is right click a Javascript event?

Tags: javascript

Is right click a Javascript event?  If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the right mouse button can be detected [through the usual mouse events (mousedown, mouseup, click)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent).  However, if you're looking for a firing event when the right-click menu is brought up, you're looking in the wrong place.  The right-click/context menu is also accessible via the keyboard (shift+F10 or context menu key on Windows and some Linux).  In this situation, the event that you're looking for is `oncontextmenu`:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function ()
{
    showCustomMenu();
    return false;     // cancel default menu
}
```

As for the mouse events themselves, browsers set a property to the event object that is accessible from the event handling function:

```
document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    var isRightMB;
    e = e || window.event;

    if ("which" in e)  // Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari/Chrome) & Opera
        isRightMB = e.which == 3; 
    else if ("button" in e)  // IE, Opera 
        isRightMB = e.button == 2; 

    alert("Right mouse button " + (isRightMB ? "" : " was not") + "clicked!");
}
```

[window.oncontextmenu - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.oncontextmenu)

Comment: Just like with the which/button issue, the 'oncontextmenu' is not implemented the same in all browsers... see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html for some of the 'gotchas'.

Comment: Keep in mind that on Mac FF *ctrl+rightclick* will come through as a left mouse click (e.which === 1), while on Mac Chrome *ctrl+rightclick* will come through as the expected right mouse click (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 3).

Comment: In Chrome 59, the right-mouse-button triggers `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`, but not `onclick`. Apparently, in Chrome, `onclick` is only triggered for the left-mouse-button. (and yes guys, I tested this multiple times) For detecting a right-mouse-click, you have to either combine `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`, or use `oncontextmenu`.

Answer (score 40):

have a look at the following jQuery code:

```
$("#myId").mousedown(function(ev){
      if(ev.which == 3)
      {
            alert("Right mouse button clicked on element with id myId");
      }
});
```

The value of `which` will be:

- **1** for the left button
- **2** for the middle button
- **3** for the right button

Comment: Eeeew, that's terrible! Why is `.which` not the same as `.button`? O.o

`.button` => *0,1,2*; `which` => *1,2,3*. that is just wrong.

Comment: It is deprecated.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the event `window.oncontextmenu`, for example:

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
  alert('Right Click')
}
```

```html
<h1>Please Right Click here!</h1>
```

Comment: this also fires left mb

Comment: Awesome +1, now how do I block the context menu? @user12345678

Comment: @Shayan e.preventDefault()

Comment: @BrianAllanWest Is that jQuery? I don't know how to use that. `window.oncontextmenu = function () {
  e.preventDefault()
}` didn't work.

Comment: @Shayan, no it's raw javascript... you would use it like this...

window.oncontextmenu = function(e) { e.preventDefault();}

this prevents the default behavior of the browser when the context menu (ie: right mouse click or hold on mac) is pressed.

Answer (score 18):

You might want to try the following properties:

1. [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) - ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mouseevent_button));
2. [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) - ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_uievent_which)) (deprecated).

---

```js
function onMouseDown(e)
{
    if (e.which === 1 || e.button === 0)
    {
        console.log('"Left" at ' + e.clientX + 'x' + e.clientY);
    }

    if (e.which === 2 || e.button === 1)
    {
        console.log('"Middle" at ' + e.clientX + 'x' + e.clientY);
    }

    if (e.which === 3 || e.button === 2)
    {
        console.log('"Right" at ' + e.clientX + 'x' + e.clientY);
    }

    if (e.which === 4 || e.button === 3)
    {
        console.log('"Back" at ' + e.clientX + 'x' + e.clientY);
    }

    if (e.which === 5 || e.button === 4)
    {
        console.log('"Forward" at ' + e.clientX + 'x' + e.clientY);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e?.cancelable && e.preventDefault());
```

```html
"How To Keep People From Pushing Your Buttons" by Albert Ellis
```

---

## MacOS

> On Windows and Linux there are modifier keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. On Mac there’s one more: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, corresponding to the property `metaKey`...
> Even if we’d like to force Mac users to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`click` – that’s kind of difficult. The problem is: a `left-click` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is interpreted as a `right-click` on MacOS, and it generates the `contextmenu` event, not `click` like Windows/Linux.
> So if we want users of all operating systems to feel comfortable, then together with `ctrlKey` we should check `metaKey`.
> For JS-code it means that we should check `if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)`...

Source: [*In this chapter we'll get into more details about mouse events and their properties...*](https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics)

[image]

Source: [https://amazon.com/dp/B07DZWLPG9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DZWLPG9)

---

Related: [*"cancelable" read-only property of the Event interface...*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable)

Comment: doesn't work for mac.. On mac, right click is control + click

Comment: @LeoCavalcante Thank you ^^ Added information about MacOS from the resource.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to detect right mouse click, you shouldn't use `MouseEvent.which` property as it is non-standard and there's large incompatibility among browsers. (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which)) You should instead use [`MouseEvent.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button). It returns a number representing a given button:

- `0`: Main button pressed, usually the left button or the un-initialized state
- `1`: Auxiliary button pressed, usually the wheel button or the middle button (if present)
- `2`: Secondary button pressed, usually the right button
- `3`: Fourth button, typically the Browser Back button
- `4`: Fifth button, typically the Browser Forward button

`MouseEvent.button` handles more input types than just standard mouse:

> Buttons may be configured differently to the standard
>   "left to right" layout. A mouse configured for left-handed use may
>   have the button actions reversed. Some pointing devices only have one
>   button and use keyboard or other input mechanisms to indicate main,
>   secondary, auxilary, etc. Others may have many buttons mapped to
>   different functions and button values.

Reference:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Answer (score 9):

Ya, though w3c says the right click can be detected by the click event, onClick is not triggered through right click in usual browsers.

In fact, right click only trigger onMouseDown onMouseUp and onContextMenu.

Thus, you can regard "onContextMenu" as the right click event. It's an HTML5.0 standard.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a great solution, especially if you are targeting newer browsers. I don't think this is an HTML5.0 only, because even IE 5.5 supports it on elements!
Here's more on which browsers support it: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can detect what mouse button was used in the "onmousedown" event... and from there determine if it was a "right-click".

Comment: @Brian: a right click will trigger `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `onclick`.  If you're looking at overriding the right-click menu, however, these events are not what you should be using (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4):

Add an e.preventDefault to stop the menu from coming up(in case you don't want it)

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('You Clicked');
}
```

```html
<h1>Right Click</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it is!

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); // true or false
}
```

Comment: Well - technically its not an "event" but it can be used.

Comment: @TimothyKhouri (and anyone else here): this is a compatible event listener function. You would pass the function object itself as the second argument to [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which would then _call_ it on the occurrence of the specified event. For example: `elem.addEventListener("click", doSomething)`

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert('Right Click')
}
```

```html
<h1>Please Right Click here!</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, oncontextmenu is probably the best alternative but be aware that it triggers on mouse down whereas click will trigger on mouse up.

Other related questions were asking about double right click - which apparently isn't supported except through manual timer checking. One reason you might want to be able to have right double click is if you need/want to support left-handed mouse input (button reversal). The browser implementations seem to make a lot of assumptions about how we should be using the available input devices.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is using jQuery to generate a custom `rightclick` event based on the default `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.
It considers the following points:

- trigger on mouseup
- trigger only when pressed mousedown on the same element before
- this code especially also works in JFX Webview (since the `contextmenu` event is not triggered there)
- it does NOT trigger when the contextmenu key on the keyboard is pressed (like the solution with the `on('contextmenu', ...)` does

```js
$(function ()
{ // global rightclick handler - trigger custom event "rightclick"
 var mouseDownElements = [];
 $(document).on('mousedown', '*', function(event)
 {
  if (event.which == 3)
  {
   mouseDownElements.push(this);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', '*', function(event)
 {
  if (event.which == 3 && mouseDownElements.indexOf(this) >= 0)
  {
   $(this).trigger('rightclick');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function()
 {
   mouseDownElements.length = 0;
 });
    // disable contextmenu
    $(document).on('contextmenu', function(event)
 {
   event.preventDefault();
 });
});



// Usage:
$('#testButton').on('rightclick', function(event)
{
  alert('this was a rightclick');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testButton">Rightclick me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get right click done is using

```
 $('classx').on('contextmenu', function (event) {

 });
```

**However** this is not cross browser solution, browsers behave differently for this event especially firefox and IE. I would recommend below for a cross browser solution

```
$('classx').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    var keycode = ( event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which );
    if (keycode === 3) {
       //your right click code goes here      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the easiest way to fire it, and it works on all browsers except application webviews like ( CefSharp Chromium etc ... ).
I hope my code will help you and good luck!

```js
const contentToRightClick=document.querySelector("div#contentToRightClick");

//const contentToRightClick=window; //If you want to add it into the whole document

contentToRightClick.oncontextmenu=function(e){
  e=(e||window.event);
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
  
  return false; //Remove it if you want to keep the default contextmenu 
}
```

```css
div#contentToRightClick{
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentToRightClick">Right click on the box !</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the given solutions using the `mouseup` or `contextmenu` events fire every time the right mouse button goes up, but they don't check wether it was down before.

---

If you are looking for a **true right click** event, which only fires when the mouse button has been **pressed and released within the same element**, then you should use the `auxclick` event. Since this fires for every none-primary mouse button you should also filter other events by checking the `button` property.

```js
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 2) alert("Right click");
});
```

You can also create your own right click event by adding the following code to the start of your JavaScript:

```
{
  const rightClickEvent = new CustomEvent('rightclick', { bubbles: true });
  window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
    if (event.button === 2) {
      event.target.dispatchEvent(rightClickEvent);
    }
  });
}
```

You can then listen for right click events via the `addEventListener` method like so:

```
your_element.addEventListener("rightclick", your_function);
```

---

Read more about the `auxclick` event on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event).

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Handle event using `jQuery` library

```
$(window).on("contextmenu", function(e)
{
   alert("Right click");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to call the function while right click event means we can use following

```
 <html lang="en" oncontextmenu="func(); return false;">
 </html>

<script>
function func(){
alert("Yes");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked with me

```
if (evt.xa.which == 3) 
{
    alert("Right mouse clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's a Javascript event, you can test it with below code.

```
<div id="contextArea">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>



    <script>
    var contextarea = $("#contextArea");
    
    contextarea.contextmenu(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("right click from p tag");
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For track right click 

window.oncontextmenu = () =>{

console.log("Right click")

}
```

Only for right click

Answer (score 0):

In **JQuery** you can detect it using the following codes:

```js
$('.target').on('contextmenu', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});

$('.target').mouseup(function (evt) {
  if (evt.which === 3) { // right-click
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
    $(this).text("RIGHT");
  }
  else if (evt.which === 1) {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    $(this).text("LEFT");
  }
});
```

```css
.target {
   display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 25px;
}

.container {

  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background: #AAA;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="target" id="target">Click</div>
  <div class="target" id="target">Right</div>
  <div class="target" id="target">Click me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, its a javascript mousedown event. There is a jQuery [plugin](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/jquery-right-click-plugin/) too to do it