# Whats wrong with my mouseup code?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, right-click, onmouseup

Trying to detect left click vs right click (without using jQuery!) and I have the following code

Javascript:

```
function cclick(e) {
   if (e.button == 1) {alert("hgbdygwea");}
   else {
      alert(e.button);
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onmouseup="cclick()" ...> <img .../> </a> <!-- also tried cclick instead of cclick() -->
```

using internet explorer 9

Comment: What's the issue? Does it fail at detecting the mouseup event?

Comment: it doesnt alert, and when i replace cclick() with cclick in the html, it says .button is undefined

Comment: Try `onmouseup="cclick(event)"`.

Comment: You don't pass the event to the callback-function

Comment: You do if you're doing it using proper event listeners. Dunno what to do if you're using `onclick`.

Comment: `button == 1` is middle click. Left button is `0` and right is `2`

Comment: @nnnnnn that works, put it as answer and i'll accept

Comment: @kirilloid yeah i just figured that out after testing nnnnnn's code :)

Comment: see more at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the event object to your function:

```
onmouseup="cclick(event);"
```

Answer (score 1):

Quirksmode has a good write up on the subject of "[Which mouse button has been clicked?](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)" and [his code works](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/LMtwd/) over the top of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Following is another approach

```
function cclick() {
   var e = window.event;
   if (e.button == 1) {alert("hgbdygwea");}
   else {
      alert(e.button);
   }
}
```

And call the function as below without passing the `event`.

```
<a onmouseup="cclick()" ...> <img .../> </a>
```

Comment: This only works in Microsoft browsers.  Other browsers do not have a window.event

Comment: Sure, as he has mentioned he need to run it on 'Internet Explorer 9'

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you.  e.button is not valid for all browsers (and I cleaned up the code).

```
function cclick(e) {
    "use strict";
    e || window.event;
    if (e.which) {
        alert((e.which === 1) ? "hgbdygwea" : e.which);
    } else {
        alert((e.button === 1) ? "hgbdygwea" : e.button);
    }
}

<a onmouseup="cclick(event)" ...> <img .../> </a> <!-- also tried cclick instead of cclick() -->
```

Comment: which browsers is e.which for? i heard it was for netscape so i didnt bother with it since its not popular anymore?