# JavaScript Rightclick and double RightClick

Tags: javascript, right-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

I'm searching an JavaScript event, i can use for the addEventListener('event',...) method.

I know there is click and dblclick. but is there an equal event for
right click and for double right click?

Comment: No, there isn't: [Is right click a Javascript event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event).

Comment: ACK, and it could only be a *DOM* event at any rate.

Comment: Ok, so i can check the double click the way seen in the link. But is there a possible way to check the right click on the document.addEventListener method? Because I really need this Event and the normal click event is not triggered by right click

Comment: A double right click? Why do you hate your users so much?

Comment: It's for private purpose only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `click` is triggered by a click, which is basically a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup` in the same place, of the primary mouse button (usually left).

A right-click does not count as a `click` for the purposes of the event. However, it still registers `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, and you can check the `Event.which` property to see if it's the right mouse button being pressed. Alternatively, you may be able to use `oncontextmenu`, which in some cases can be considered the same as a right-click.

That still leaves the problem of a double-right-click, though. For this to work, you would need to measure the time between two right-clicks, and if you deem it short enough to be a double click, then handle it as such. It's a very complex setup, but double-right-clicks are not user-friendly at all so perhaps you should consider an alternative input?

Comment: This is nothing for a User ;) It should be an chrome-addon for me. I used the add on "Double Click closes Tab" for firefox where i set up the double richt click to close my tab. And on Chrome it doesnt work. I wanted to get it to work again