# Can I handle a right click event on an HTML <button /> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen plenty of questions and answers on SO and elsewhere that talk about right click events and how to catch and handle them with JavaScript, generally using the `.button` attribute of the `event` object generated by the browser.

However, the one thing I haven't found, probably because it's a pretty weird request, is how to catch and handle right clicks on an HTML `<button />` element. Buttons are not handled the same way by the browser as other elements. Most importantly, it seems that a right click on a button doesn't do anything. No context menu and, from what I can tell, no event.

Am I wrong? I hope so, because it will make my life easier. If not, I can simulate a button with a div and some CSS, but I'd rather avoid it. Any thoughts?

(PS: This is for a silly side project, so don't worry about me trying to put a button-right-click-based interface in front of any customers or anything. I'm well aware of how horrible that interface would probably be.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: "I can* simulate a button with a div"

Comment: The `contextmenu` event fires for me on Chrome, Firefox, Opera (all on Linux) and on IE10 on Windows 7: http://jsbin.com/oduhak/1 Don't have earlier handy IEs to check (too many VMs running already).

Comment: @DevlshOne not a duplicate. As I mentioned in the first sentence of my post, while I've seen that post and others like it, it doesn't seem to apply for buttons. Though I'll check on the `contextmenu` event as TJCrowder suggested

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just add a `onmousedown` listener, check which mouse was pressed:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("test").onmousedown = function(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        alert("right clicked!");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jmmqz/

Comment: @IanClark It does in the latest version: 22.0

Comment: I'm going to use `onmouseup` instead, but thanks! I forgot about these guys. It's really weird that these events are generated but not an `onclick` event.

Comment: @KenB -- All good, first time writing something like this, happy it worked!

Answer (score 13):

http://jsfiddle.net/jqYN5/ is this what you are looking for? Adding `context-menu`:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" id="btn">
<button id="btn2">right click</button>`
```

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  alert('click!')
}

document.getElementById('btn2').oncontextmenu = function() {
  alert('right click!')
}
```

Comment: That's definitely another way to go about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or, with perhaps a bit more beginner level understanding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseclick(ele, e) {
if (e.type == 'click') {
    alert('Left Click Detected!');
}
    if (e.type == 'contextmenu') {
    alert('Right Click Detected!');
}
}
</script>

<a href="/" 
onclick="mouseclick(this, event)" 
oncontextmenu="mouseclick(this, event)" >link name</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of "context Menu" also :

```
document.getElementById('btn2').oncontextmenu = function() {
 alert('right click!')
}
```