# Javascript redirect when right clicking

Tags: javascript

How do you make javascript redirect when a person right clicks? Is it even possible?

```
    var message="MESSAGE TO USER"

    function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message); 
window.open("site.com/whatever.php");
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
window.open("site.com/whatever.php");
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

I'm trying to insert the window.open("site.com/whatever.php"); into the script but having no success.

Edit

I want the redirect to take place when the alert box has been closed. Sorry for not making this clear before.

Comment: By saying "redirect" did you mean opening a web page in a separate window or navigate way to a different page on the same window ?

Comment: either of the above although preferrable a seperate window

Comment: What browser + version you are testing this on ?

Comment: It is obvious from your code that it only works on IE4.0 and Netscape Navigator 4.0.

Comment: Alert box works fine on FF23. Along with Chrome and many other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (document.layers){
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
  document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}
```

to

```
if (document.layers){
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
  document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}
else { 
  document.onmousedown = function (e) {
  if (e.button == 2)
  {
      alert("Ouch! that hurts. Please do not right click!");
      setTimeout(function() { location.href="http://www.google.com/"; }, 500);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear before. Your script works. But I want the redirect to take place after the alert box is shown. However if it cannot be done i'll just stick with this and add a delay on the redirect.

Comment: That works perfectly. Although I think a redirect in the same window would look alot better. Thanks

Comment: You're a star my friend ^^

Comment: @user2425108 you should accept the answer by clicking the check if you think it is a good answer because it gives the answerer 15 reputation and lets people know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the complete URL with protocol:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
```

The rightclick issue has been answered here:

[Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: exactly what you just said

Comment: So you're saying window.open('http://www.google.com'); does not work and there are no correct answers in the link I posted?

Comment: that's exaxctly what i'm saying. But appreciate the help.

and I tried http://google.com. Like you said also.

Comment: It seems the right click mouse event doesn't open a new window. I can get it to open a new window while it's displaying the alert box, however this is not what I want. I want the redirect to take place straight after the alert box is shown (ie closed). That way a user has time to read it before they are auto redirected.