# Can you use regular javascript functions in the navigator toolbar Onsen UI?

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

```
<ons-navigator-toolbar right-button-icon="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg icon-white" on-right-button-click="ons.slidingMenu.toggleMenu();">
```

I want to be able to call a standard java function on-right-button-click.

I tried on-right-button-click="alert('Test');"

Comment: have a look on [right click event in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs will look into the scope for the function. It will not look at the global window object.

However, you can attach the alert function to the $rootScope

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch', 'onsen.directives']);   

    myApp.run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.alert = function(message){
            window.alert(message);
        }
    });
```