# How I can reduce the length with each left click and right click each increase it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition, subtraction

Example:

```
div.my{width: 100%;}

<div class="my"></div>
```

left click:

```
div{width: 75%;}
```

Right click:

```
div{width: 100%;}
```

Comment: With jquery, thx a lot!

Comment: i guess you should use some code. BwaBascript or something. Not sure though.

Comment: Should be trivial -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hmZ9k/**

Comment: The question should be in the body of the post, not the subject. Detecting "right click" is unreliable at best across browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the `width` of the `target` as 100 [As mentioned in the post].

Listen to the `mousedown` event and determine the mouse button clicked from the `which` attribute of the `event` passed to the `callback function`.

In the `callback function` depending on the mouse button clicked `add or subtract` the desired `unit`[25 in this case].

Apply the calculated width to the target.

Please refer the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/NLvL8/1/) for working example.

```js
var elasticDivWidth = 100;
$('.elastic-div').on('mousedown', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  if( (e.which == 1) ) {
    elasticDivWidth = elasticDivWidth - 25;
  } else if( (e.which == 3) ) {
    elasticDivWidth = elasticDivWidth + 25;
  }
  $(this).css('width', elasticDivWidth + '%');
}).on('contextmenu', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.elastic-div {
  height: 200px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elastic-div"></div>
```

Comment: Strange. Still the answer is down voted. You should up vote and accept the answer it it serves the purpose.

Comment: Not my downvote, but code only answers are not liked.

Comment: I hear you. In the above example, isn't the code sufficient for the explanation. I would certainly add explanation in the future answers.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include an explanation, then the down–voter can remove the vote. And "the code is the best documentation" indicates an expectation that reverse engineering intent from code will arrive at the same place, *cf* [*Chinese whispers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).

Comment: Added explanation as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be careful using left click and right click in browsers.  Not all browsers support right clicks.  If you still want to implement this, the right click can be detected through the `oncontextmenu` event.

[This Stack Overflow post has an example for you in JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Basically, you are going to need to script a function that triggers when `oncontextmenu` occurs.  You'll need to access the element via `document.getElementById()` or similar DOM traversal function.  Then change the width via the element's style property in JS.

You cannot access the right click using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: damm, i try but my rep is 15<, =( sry

Comment: +1 for pointing out issues with right–click. It's is not a good idea to rely on it.