# How to capture right click on a specify element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I'm trying to make a zoomable image block in an HTML page using javascript.
Now zooming in is finished by capturing Doubleclick event and some simple functions.
Problem is here that I have some elements (div tags like tile) and want to have a function called when right clicked on some of them.
How can I do this?

Comment: Search for "contextmenu".

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the contextmenu event:

```
<div oncontextmenu="javascript:alert('Right Click Performed!');return false;">
    Right click on me!
</div>
```

And then add a listener:

```
el.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('Right Click Performed!');
    return false;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

javascripts `event.button` function will give you the mouse button you clicked.

`<img onMouseDown="alert(event.button)" src="yourimage" />`

right click should return 2 but best check each browser