# Right Click in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, mouseevent, clojurescript

Could anyone tell me how to produce a right-click event handler in Clojure? I am familiar with ":on-click" for simple clicks but not right or double clicks. Can't seem to find any helpful resources online. Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: Thanks but that is for Javascript not Clojure. I understand that JS is running under the hood of Clojure but looking for a code snippet in Clojure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frequently in ClojureScript the Google Closure library ([Event Handling |  Closure Library | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/events_tutorial)) is used instead of raw JS. The [events (Closure Library API Documentation - JavaScript)](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.events.html) namespace contains the [`goog.events.EventType`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.events.EventType.html) enumeration which specifies each individual event type:

```
(ns test.core
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom]
            [goog.events :as events]))

(letfn [(menu-listener [event] 
          (.log js/console (str "contextmenu " (.-button event))))
        (click-listener [event]
          (let [btn (.-button event)
                msg (if (= btn 2) "Right-click" (str "Button " btn))] 
            (.log js/console msg)))]

  (events/listen (dom/getElement "click-target") "contextmenu" menu-listener)
  (events/listen (dom/getElement "click-target") "click" click-listener))   

;; src/test/core.cljs
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>contextmenu</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="click-target">Right click on me</p> 
    <script src="out/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- index.html -->
```

Observe:

- A right-click (button 2) fires the `contextmenu` listener. The `click` listener doesn't get to see it (even if there is no `contextmenu` listener).
- A second right-click will dismiss the context menu but neither listener is fired.

Comment: The link for the events library is broken, here's a link to the source for the event types: https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/events/eventtype.js

Answer (score 5):

Using `om` I got right click as context-menu event. Button number is 2 for right button:

```
{:onContextMenu (fn [e]
                   (prn e (.-button e)))}
```

or in plain html+cljs:

```
  <div id="btn">Click me</div>

  (.addEventListener (.getElementById js/document "btn")
    "contextmenu" (fn [e] (prn e (.-button e))))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent