# Can't get HTML5 2D context to draw a point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw all the points a user clicks on the canvas until the user clicks on the first clicked. I am able to store them on a hidden input, but I can't get them to draw/show ("ctx.fillRect(pos_x, pos_y, 1, 1);") on screen properly. What is my code missing? I only see the first point and it is not even on the place I clicked (viewing using IE Edge). Eventually I would like to add the lines drawn by the points.

Also, as an extra, could someone please help me determine if the click was within the canvas for the time the code is detecting the context menu?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c;
        var ctx;

        function wireUp()
        {
            // Initiate context. Do only once
            c = document.getElementById('imgContainer');
            ctx = c.getContext('2d');

            // Store points
            keepPoints('hiddenMap');

            // Override context when user has clicked within the canvas
            window.oncontextmenu = function ()
            {
                // TO DO: Detect click was within canvas area
                clearMap('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap');
                return false; // cancel default menu
            }

            document.getElementById('imgContainer').onclick = function (e) {
                // Detect RMB. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event
                var isRightMB;
                e = e || window.event;

                if ("which" in e)  // Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari/Chrome) & Opera
                    isRightMB = e.which == 3; 
                else if ("button" in e)  // IE, Opera 
                    isRightMB = e.button == 2;

                if(!isRightMB)
                {
                    pointDetected('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap', e);
                }
                else
                { // Clear points, drawn and on map
                    alert("RMB");
                    clearMap('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap');
                }
            };
        }
        function clearMap(container, map)
        {
            // Clear drawn points
            var canvas = document.getElementById(container);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Clear map
            var hMap = document.getElementById(map);
            hMap.value = "";
        }
        function pointDetected(container, map, event)
        {
            //alert("Oh my! " + container);
            pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById(container).offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById(container).offsetTop;
            //alert(pos_x + ", " + pos_y);

            var hMap = document.getElementById(map);
            if(hMap.value) // Check if the map has already points and append with comma
            {
                hMap.value = hMap.value + "; " + pos_x + ", " + pos_y;
            }
            else
            {
                hMap.value = pos_x + ", " + pos_y;
            }
            alert(hMap.value);

            // Draw a point where clicked
            ctx.fillRect(pos_x, pos_y, 1, 1);
        }
        function keepPoints(container)
        {
            // Stores all the points that the user has selected
            var hidden = document.createElement("input");
            var typeAtt = document.createAttribute("type");
            typeAtt.value = "hidden";
            hidden.setAttributeNode(typeAtt);
            hidden.id = container;
            document.body.appendChild(hidden);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="wireUp();">
    <canvas style="background:url('untitled.png');width:819px;height:460px;border-style:solid;" id="imgContainer">
    </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't set your canvas dimensions only through CSS, use its `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido, it helped. Posting the code working.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to create the lines using ctx.moveTo and ctx.lineTo. That and Kaiido's comment, helped me get the code to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var c;
            var ctx;

        function wireUp()
        {
            // Initiate context. Do only once
            c = document.getElementById('imgContainer');
            ctx = c.getContext('2d');
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";

            // Store points
            keepPoints('hiddenMap');

            // Override context when user has clicked within the canvas
            window.oncontextmenu = function (e)
            {
                // TO DO: Detect click was within canvas area
                clearMap('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap');
                return false; // cancel default menu
            }

            document.getElementById('imgContainer').onclick = function (e) {
                // Detect RMB. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event
                var isRightMB;
                e = e || window.event;

                if ("which" in e)  // Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari/Chrome) & Opera
                    isRightMB = e.which == 3; 
                else if ("button" in e)  // IE, Opera 
                    isRightMB = e.button == 2;

                if(!isRightMB)
                {
                    pointDetected('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap', e);
                }
                else
                { // Clear points, drawn and on map
                    alert("RMB");
                    clearMap('imgContainer', 'hiddenMap');
                }
            };
        }
        function clearMap(container, map)
        {
            // Clear drawn points
            var canvas = document.getElementById(container);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Clear map
            var hMap = document.getElementById(map);
            hMap.value = "";
        }
        function pointDetected(container, map, event)
        {
            //alert("Oh my! " + container);
            pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById(container).offsetLeft;
            pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById(container).offsetTop;
            //alert(pos_x + ", " + pos_y);

            var hMap = document.getElementById(map);
            if(hMap.value) // Check if the map has already points and append with comma
            {
                hMap.value = hMap.value + ";" + pos_x + "," + pos_y;
        -       // Continue from last drawn point
                ctx.lineTo(pos_x, pos_y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
            else
            {
                hMap.value = pos_x + "," + pos_y;
                // Draw a point where clicked
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(pos_x, pos_y);
            }
            //alert(hMap.value);

            //ctx.fillRect(pos_x, pos_y, 1, 1);
        }
        function keepPoints(container)
        {
            // Stores all the points that the user has selected
            var hidden = document.createElement("input");
            var typeAtt = document.createAttribute("type");
            typeAtt.value = "hidden";
            hidden.setAttributeNode(typeAtt);
            hidden.id = container;
            document.body.appendChild(hidden);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="wireUp();">
    <canvas style="background:url('untitled.png');border-style:solid;" width="819" height="460" id="imgContainer">
    </canvas>
</body>
```