# Attaching Right Click Event on Dynamically Created Elements

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

Below is the code that dynamically creates an element and attach an `onclick` event.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.onclick = function(e){
    console.debug(e);           
}

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('myid_templates_editor_center_menu');
parent[0].appendChild(div);
```

How about attaching a right click event?

Comment: haven't you tried oncontextmenu

Comment: check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is right click a Javascript event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.oncontextmenu = function(e){
    console.debug(e);           
}

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('myid_templates_editor_center_menu');
parent[0].appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question consists of two parts:

**1) How to attach the right-click event?**

Answer: use the `contextmenu` event.

**2) How to attach an event to dynamically created elements?**

Answer: the idea is to attach the event to the parent element that will contain your newly created element. The event will propagate along the DOM until it reaches your parent element.

**Working Example:**

```
//get parent elements
var elements = getElementsByClassName('myid_templates_editor_center_menu'); 

//attach to the first found parent element
elements[0].addEventlistener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    console.log("right clicked!");
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "right click";
  div.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    console.debug(e.type, e);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
div.oncontextmenu = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.debug(e);           
}
```

instead onclick

Answer (score 0):

Working Example

```
node.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
alert('success! - Right Click');
return false;
```

}, false);

Codepen : 
http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/WogoVB