# How to select the right clicked word?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code. This is what it does. When you highlight/select some text on a webpage by clicking and dragging, right click to see the context menu, and when the menu item is clicked, the highlighted text shows up in an alert box. I want to modify this code so that the user doesn't have to highlight any text by click and drag. All they have to do is right click on a word and choose the context menu item. The word/text they right clicked on should appear as alert.

```
let contextMenuItem = {
    "id": "helloWorld",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
  });

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {
        let inputString = clickData.selectionText;
        alert(inputString);
})
```

Comment: This my old answer can be usefull ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571090/detect-which-word-has-been-right-clicked-on-within-a-text/43571580#43571580

Comment: looks really confusing, those answers.

Comment: @NoobCoder it is a bit simpler than that. you just use the Range API `caretRangeFromPoint` I have added my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, extensions have a **"strict"** permission model. When you give permission for [contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), you are limited to the following contexts:

*"all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio", "launcher", "browser_action", or "page_action"*

## Bad UX

If it had a **"word"** or even a **"text"** context, it creates a non consistent user experience. Users are not familiar with right click doing actions on text within a web browser.

If you wanted such action, you need to introduce a [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to add a mouse event to **"automatically"** select that word using the [JavaScript Selection APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). If you wanted this, you need to expose more **"permissions"** to your extension to support this experience. Users might not like that.

## Example

If this is the experience the extension needs, just create a [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)  which automatically selects that word. Something like this will work, which will create a caret range from the mouse position and modify its selection to that word. Note, within the permissions, I just enabled google.com, this is where the content script will inject.

**contentscript.js**

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    if (e.button !== 2) {
        return
    }

    const selection = window.getSelection()
    selection.removeAllRanges()

    const range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    range.expand('word')

    selection.addRange(range)
});
```

**background.js**

```
const menu = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'id': 'helloWorld',
    'title': 'Hello "%s"',
    'contexts': ['selection']
})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((clickData) => {
    const inputString = clickData.selectionText
    console.log(inputString)
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "contextMenus",
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "35.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```