# Ctrl+u double make not hide

Tags: javascript

The below code works fine, but if I click double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then it opens all. How can I disable all?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, right-click, <kbd>F12</kbd> key and more key for hide code?

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 117)) { //Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
    alert('not allowed');
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: May you edit you stacksnippet? The script tags are not needed.

Comment: Even if you block keys and context menus, There are many other ways to reach your code. For Ex: in chrome, options->more tools->developer tools. If you want to hide your JS code, i suggest you obfuscate javascript. https://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```js
/*function check(e)
    {
    alert(e.keyCode);
    }*/
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 117)) { //Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
    alert('not allowed');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `e.preventDefault()` function. it will stop the browser to do the default actions when in this case a key combination has been pressed.

The key code for the `F12` button is `123`. To detect the 'contextmenu' event (user clicks right button), you also have to use the preventdefault function to avoid opening the contextmenu. Maybe this will help you:

Live preview: https://jsfiddle.net/cmLf34h3/1/

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 117) || e.keyCode === 123) { //Alt+c, Alt+v will also be disabled sadly.
    alert('not allowed');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
};

window.oncontextmenu = function (e)
{
    alert("You have tested if your right-mousebutton is still working. This alert confirms it's still working, have a nice day!")
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;     // cancel default menu
}
```

Source for the right-click function: [Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Note: You cannot 100% prevent these actions, there is always a backdoor to bypass this.

I hope this helps