# Getting the coordinates of the image through jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding an image inside a div. I want to get the coordinates of the image (and not the coordinates of the screen) at the point where the user right clicks over that image. How can i do that?

```
<div id="Boma" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; position: relative">
  <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" alt="Boma" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">  
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/akiwo

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to checkout the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) jQuery function:

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) **relative to the document**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event) is a pretty clear and usefull comment about using Right Click in *Javascript*.

And you should now have all the tools to create what you want to do. Hope it will help.