# how to force a user to embed image or signup

Tags: image, embed

while browsing i saw this website,
https://deavita.com/lifestyle/haustiere/wellensittiche-halten-artgerecht-vogel-kaefig-voliere.html
checked a post and wanted to download the image.
when right click on image, it gave me two option. 1) embed the image 2) or signup 
so my question is how can i add such same functoin in my website. 
and is that a plugin or something else? if plugin, plz tell the name of plugin, i try to detect plguin but non of them have such thing.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is handled by javascript. you can find out if the user has fired a **mouse click** event on an element and check if it is a right-click or left-click, then call the desired function. It is also possible to change the browser's default context menu when right-clicking on an element.
For more details check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405835/2991891