# Is there a way to register a context click but by using the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I know we can capture key events with event.which, but for accessibility purposes we need to be able to navigate to a custom context click (right click) menu. Is there a way to register a context click, both for mac and windows?

Comment: You're looking for the window.oncontextmenu event.  This event triggers for me in chrome / windows on right click and keyboard context menu actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: "for accessibility purposes we need to be able to navigate to a custom context click (right click) menu" sounds sketchy. Could you explain more, please? The expected result of a right click would be the user-agent's context menu.