# How to properly detect mouse right click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to detect mouse right click but the following code only detects the left click.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
    return false;
}

document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log("clicked", e);
}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix this?

I'm using the latest Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Check if e.which == 3, if that's true then it's a right click. Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: @Ameer but it doesn't even print out the log on right-click before I can even check which.

Comment: Because you return false from oncontextmenu. Check which button in onclick and return false there instead if it's right one

Comment: I don't get it. I would appreciate a full working code as an answer.

Comment: on a normal modern JS note: don't use 1998 style event handlers. Use `addEventListener`, on the correct object, with the correct event name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.oncontextmenu` is already detecting mouse right click. What it does is disabling the default browser right click context menu for now, but you can add any additional code above it to trigger whenever right click event is performed.

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
  console.log("right clicked");
    return false;
}
```

You can try by running the code snippet and right clicking the empty space. Left clicking will not print the console.log.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, you could also use `addEventListener` to listen to `contextmenu`.

```js
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log("right clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This Function to get right & left click event
But  You Have To Use onmousedown instead using onclick

```
function myFunction() {
var rightclick;
if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
isRclick =  rightclick; // true or false


alert(isRclick);
```

}