# How to do eventListener by holding right click using VANILLA JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the div wherever the cursor is holding right click.

in my case i have this code

```
<div class="d-none" id="item"></div>
```

```
#item{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: royalblue;
  /* transform: translate(calc(287px - 50%), calc(77px - 50%)); */
}
.d-none{
  display: none;
}
```

```
var myMouseX, myMouseY;

function getXYPosition(e) {
    myMouseX = (e || event).clientX;
    myMouseY = (e || event).clientY;
    
    getPosition(myMouseX, myMouseY);
    
    
    function getPosition(x, y) {
        console.log('X = ' + x + '; Y = ' + y);
      let div = document.querySelector("#item");
      if (div.classList.contains('d-none')) {
        div.classList.remove('d-none');
      } else {
        div.classList.add('d-none');
      }
      divX = x + "px";
      divY = y + "px";
      div.style.transform = `translate(calc(`+divX+` - 50%) , calc(`+divY+` - 50%))`;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('click', function () {
  getXYPosition()
})
```

or you can see my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aditya_4420/bkq326eu/167/)

Its work on left click by default using `window.addEventListener('click')`

so how do i change from left click to holding right click a few seconds

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event

Comment: Have you tried  `addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {  e.preventDefault(); getXYPosition(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MouseEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) (with its `mousedown` and `mouseup` events) lets us **check the `event.button` property** to learn which mouse button the user is activating.  And we can keep track of how much time passes between `mousedown` and `mouseup` to **decide what to do when the mouse button is released**, such as running a custom `showOrHideDiv` function.

And the [`contextmenu` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) fires after a right-click (unless the relevant context menu is already visible, I guess.) We can **suppress the default contextmenu behavior if necessary** -- although this power should be used sparingly if at all.

Note that the technique used here is problematic in that it **assumes the user will never use their keyboard to see the context menu**, which will eventually cause accessibility snafus and other unpleasant surprises for users. This is why hijacking the default `right-click` behavior should be avoided if possible (maybe in favor of something like `Shift + right-click`) unless the user explictly opts in to the new behavior.

```js
// Defines constants and adds main (`mousedown`) listener
const
  div = document.querySelector("#item"),
  RIGHT = 2,
  DELAY = 150;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', forceDelay);

// Main listener sets subsequent listeners
function forceDelay(event){

  // Right mouse button must be down to proceed
  if(event.button != RIGHT){ return; }

  // Enables contextmenu and disables custom response
  document.removeEventListener('contextmenu', suppressContextMenu);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', showOrHideDiv);

  // After 150ms, disables contextmenu and enables custom response
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      document.addEventListener('contextmenu', suppressContextMenu);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', showOrHideDiv);
    },
    DELAY
  );
}

// The `contextmenu` event listener
function suppressContextMenu(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}

// The `mouseup` event listener
function showOrHideDiv(event){
  if(event.button != RIGHT){ return; }
  const
    x = event.clientX,
    y = event.clientY;
  div.classList.toggle('d-none'); // classList API includes `toggle`
  div.style.transform = `translate(calc(${x}px - 50%), calc(${y}px - 50%))`;
}
```

```css
#item{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: royalblue; }
.d-none{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="item" class="d-none"></div>
```

**EDIT**
**Note:** The script works properly when tested in a standalone HTML file using Chrome, but (at least with my laptop's touchpad) behaves strangely when run here in a Stack Overflow snippet. If you experience similar issues, you can paste it into a <script> element in an HTML file (with the CSS in a <style> element) to see it working.