# How to detect mouse right-click in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm trying to detect left and right mouse clicks. I have a div with an `onClick` handler attached to it. This is what it looks like:

`<div className={styles.itemSlot} onClick={this.onClick}></div>`

And this is what the 'onClick' looks like:

```
  private readonly onClick = (evt: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
    if (evt.button === 1) {
      console.log('Left Click')
    }
    if (evt.button === 2) {
      console.log('Right Click')
    }
  };
```

The left click gets detected, but when I click the right button on the mouse, nothing happens. The same is true for the wheel or middle button. Only the left click gets detected.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: The [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event may help you with your functionality

Comment: @tomerpacific and @MikeS. Unfortunately no. I've seen that answer and I don't want to use `oncontextmenu`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `evt.nativeEvent.button`? Also could you provide a `console.log(evt.button, evt.nativeEvent.button)` both when you are left-clicking and right-clicking?

Comment: You could use `onmousedown` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and check the MouseEvent.button. But in the end it may just be the same as `oncontextmenu`. What do you mean with you 'don't want to use' it?